First n-element Sum of the First Order Polynomial Series
in order to sum a first order polynomial series that goes like:
$a_0 = 100,$
$a_1 = a_0 + 55 + 10*(1)$ (where n is the index)
$a_2 = a_1 + 55 + 10*(2)$
$a_3 = a_2 + 55 + 10*(3)$
...
$a_n = a_{n-1} + 55+10n$
What is the correct approach to find the formula for sum? How do I derive the general sum equation from $a_0$ to $a_n$ and what will be the mathematical notation for this polynomial? Thank you.
$\sum_{i=0}^n [Insert \text{  }the \text{  }formula\text{  } here]= {final\text{  }equation?}$

Whenever I see a progression where the change itself changes (think two degrees of change), I think quadratic. Quadratics only need 3 points to be unique. Let $f(n):=a_n$ for notation purposes.
We know that $f(n)=an^2+bn+c$. Since $f(0)=100$, then $a(0)^2+b(0)+c=100$ meaning that $c=100$.
Here are the first few values of $a_n$ or $f(n)$: $100, 165, 240$. From $100$ to $165$ is $65$ and from $165$ to $240$ is $75$. The change between the change is therefore $10$. It is a fact that in a quadratic, the second degree of change equals $2a$ (has to do with second derivatives). Therefore $2a=10$ so $a=5$.
Solving for $b$, we know that $f(1)=165=5(1)^2+(1)b+100$ and therefore $165=105+b$. $b=60$.
$\Rightarrow f(n)=5n^2+60n+100$
Summing this from $0$ to $k$ gives $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k}(5n^2+60n+100)$. You can solve this summation by breaking it down, pulling constant coefficients out, and using the sum of squares, numbers, etc.
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k}(5n^2+60n+100)=\frac{5}{6}(k+1)(2k^2+37k+120)$
